# How to override exception class

Tags: java

How to override exception class so that when ever a exception is thrown , I want  that overridden method to be executed. I am looking for something similar to testwatcher in junit.Also is there any where I can get  the complete strace of the first exception thrown in a program?

Comment: This doesn’t make sense, where should this method be executed? The only thing that should be executed is the constructor, so maybe put the logic there.

Comment: Hi my prob is I am working in a selenium framework based on POM . We have various functions which we use in my test script class. These functions which we call are framework functions which we don't have access to . So suppose I have a settext function and I use it in my script ,and when I execute it and say the object is not found , the exception thrown is handled in the function and exception is printed as a text in console. I am trying for a solution where when ever a exception takes place , I will read through the exception and get the root cause and store it for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways to do it.

First one is to use `Aspects`, but in this case you have to use `ajc` compiler instead of `javac`.

Second one is to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`, see Rod Hilton's ["Global Exception Handling"](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2006/06/13/java-5-global-exception-handling/) blog post for an example.